# Django JS - downloading Django-generated file to client

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a Django code that generates a file on server-side and then I want the user to be able to choose a local location on his computer (f.e., Destktop) and actually download the file.

```
def my_view(request):
    # Generating content    
    myfile.write(content.encode('cp1251'))
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/force-download')
    file_name = get_declaration_file_name(declaration_instance)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' %       
                   smart_str(file_name)
    response['X-Sendfile'] = smart_str(myfile)
    return response
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#create_declaration_form').submit(function(e) { 
        create_declaration_files(e, $(this).find('button[type="submit"]'))});
});
    function create_declaration_files(e, $button)
    {
        // ...
        $.post ('/my_view/', data, function() {
            // OPEN DIALOG FOR CHOOSING DESTINATION FOLDER
            // DOWNLOAD THE FILE
        })
    }
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
```

The issue is that after surfing the internet, I can't figure out what should be the JS code that receives the RESPONSE from Django (containing the target file). Previously, I easily developed code for uploading files, but having trouble now with downloading.

Comment: What do you need the JS for? If you put a link to my_view (and hook it up in the urls) the download will work without any JS.

Comment: Could you provide some code ? I don't really get your point regarding putting a link and hooking up in the url.

Comment: I've updated the code to provide more details.